# Azure Function App : @EventHubTrigger set different batch size for each EventHubTrigger Function

Tags: java, azure, configuration, azure-functions

How to provide different configuration for each @EventHubTrigger function,

Current: at **host.json**

```
"eventHubs": {
            "batchCheckpointFrequency": 1,
            "eventProcessorOptions": {
                "enableReceiverRuntimeMetric": true,
                "invokeProcessorAfterReceiveTimeout": false,
                "maxBatchSize": 30,
                "prefetchCount": 10,
                "receiveTimeout": "00:05:00"
            }
        }
```

In current scenario having 3 function based on EventTrigger event, which is common for all.

I would like to use different configuration for each function in an *Azure Function App*.

Comment: host.json is different for each function app anyway. i dont understand what you are trying now

Comment: host.json is different for each FunctionApp not for each function, I want separate configuration for each function.

Comment: the answer is no way! haha

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported as of now, then you need to create separate function Apps with separate configuraiton.

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json)

The host.json metadata file contains global configuration options that affect **all functions** for a function app.

Comment: any other way instead of host.json but I need EventTrigger function